# How to fetch the combination of year, month and the weeknumber (YYYYMMWW) in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get the current year, month and week number, which I have fetched as the following:

select year(getdate()) as yr, month(getdate()) as month, datepart(wk,day(getdate())) as weeknumber

But I need it in the following format "yyyymmww" or "yyyy-mm-ww".

Comment: Concatenate the values.

Comment: `datepart(wk,day(getdate()))` you probably wanted `datepart(wk, getdate())`

Comment: @lptr that's it, that works thanks a lot

Comment: there is a difference in weeks for the US and Europe and other continents. If you want the ISO week then use `DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, getdate()) as iso_weeknumber`

Comment: Please do not forget to alo adjust the year in case you're aiming at ISO_WEEK like so:
`SELECT datepart(year,getDate)+CASE WHEN datepart(ISO_WEEK,getdate())>50 AND datepart(month,getdate())=1 THEN -1 WHEN datepart(ISO_WEEK,getdate())<2 AND datepart(month,getdate())=12 THEN +1 ELSE 0 END`